# iOS Why wouldn't exiting a method in the main thread from a sub-thread work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I'm initiating an asynch thread using grand central dispatch in objective-c using the following code:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

}
```

For a *very* long time I was having trouble correctly exiting the IBAction that triggers this. I do a lot of the code in the main thread wrapped inside this GCD thread using this code:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

}
```

What I originally tried to do was simply put the return; statement inside this mainQueue block. After a lot of fiddling I discovered that to break out of the IBAction that contains all this the return; needs to be in the GCD queue.

Why is this? I thought that return would exit methods regardless of where it is in the program. Also, is it even possible to exit from a nested queue call like this?

Comment: What work are you running in a different thread? Network code? An extensive operation etc?

If you are going to use different threads, you should expect that code to finish later, responding to that finish should be through callback methods etc. Just because you have wrapped some code in the main thread, does not mean it will be run straight away

Comment: @Naughty_Ottsel the check to see if I should return is the first action after starting the asynch thread. Any network intensive stuff is done after. Also, the main queue is called directly after the check to see if it should return, so there shouldn't be much delay before calling that. The return check that was in the main queue before I figured out where it was supposed to go was also the first action in that block, so hopefully no delay there.

Comment: In theory, running the main code, in the async thread, should be safe. In my opinion, you should run the main thread code through another GCD block. I think the NSOperation code is kind of a "gets added and will be run eventually" GCD has a bit of higher priority. FYI:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});

Comment: @Naughty_Ottsel I see no evidence to support that claim that `NSOperationQueue` rendition "will be be run eventually" and that GCD has higher priority. Personally, I would also use GCD to dispatch back to the main queue if I was in GCD block, but merely for stylistic consistency, but I do not think it's correct to claim operation queues are materially slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block is similar to a function. It is a different context from the code which defines it. A `return` statement within a block exits that block, not the method or function within which the block was defined. (If the block has a non-`void` return type, the `return` statement also gives the return value of the block.)

For example, consider:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int (^block)(int, int) = ^int(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

    printf("3 + 5 = %d\n", block(3, 5));
}
```

The `return` statement in the block does not return from `foo()`, it just returns from the block and gives the return value of the block. The block is like a little separate function except that its code is provided right in the middle of another function and it can capture local variables from the context of its definition.

Now, the block given to `dispatch_async()` does not take arguments or return a value, but the flow control of the `return` statement is the same. It returns from that block, not from the method or function containing the call to `dispatch_async()`. In particular, since `dispatch_async()` runs the block asynchronously, it is quite possible (even likely) that the block won't be run until well after the method or function that called `dispatch_async()` has already exited.